# cairosvg svg2png throwing unrelated error

Tags: python, cairo

I have been doing some simple testing with cairosvg last night and everything worked perfectly, being able to convert svg to png.
This morning I ran the same code but it started to throw an error I was not able to find anywhere.

My code is as following:

```
import cairosvg

cairosvg.svg2png(url='layout.svg', write_to='image.png', output_height=200)
```

and this is the following error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1713, in feed
    self.parser.Parse(data, False)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0
```

I did not run updates during the night so I don't really know what changed.
A few things I tried to do:

- reinstalled cairo and related packages with brew
- Upgraded python3

Nothing worked and I still get the same error which seems unrelated to what I am trying to do.

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Well, what is the beginning of `layout.svg`? According to the error message, the very beginning of the file is not valid XML.

Comment: @UliSchlachter your comment actually sparked the solution.
What happened is that for some reason running cairosvg has corrupted the original svg, hence why it could not recognise the file.
Kind of a noob mistake to not check the file itlsef, since it was still showing up file as a preview.